# "setTimeout" to a custom javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

can we add a `"setTimeout"` to a custom javascript variable?

I am trying to add a setTimeout  to a function and its giving me a parse error.

```
   setTimeout( function() {
      var el = {{findclosetjobs}}({{Click Element}}, 'span[class="select2-selection__rendered"]');
      return typeof el !== 'undefined' ? el.innerText : undefined;
    }, 1000);
```

Please advise.

Comment: What is the exact error? Do you literally have `{{findclosetjobs}}` and `{{Click Element}}` in the script, or are those replaced by a template engine of some kind? Do you have something that works without `setTimeout`?

Comment: @Ryan in GTM you use {{ }} to reference other GTM variables. I believe  {{findclosetjobs}} is custom funciton and {{Click Element}} is GTM built in variable.

Comment: @Matus: Whoops, I totally missed the tag. Thanks.

Comment: (The comment still applies, though – exact error, something else that *does* work, and possibly the definition of `findclosetjobs`, please.)

Comment: @Ryan heres the error JavaScript Compiler Error job_variable 
Error at line 5, character 13: Parse error. ')' expected

Comment: @Ryan {{findclosetjobs}} is custom funciton and {{Click Element}} is GTM built in variable and findclosetjobs is called. the issue arises when i add the setTimeout function. dont know if we can add a settimeout function to a custom javascript variable in GTM. also the errors is as follows "JavaScript Compiler Error job_variable Error at line 5, character 13: Parse error. ')' expected"

Comment: you can definitely use timeout, maybe you are looking at the wrong script and the problem is actually in findclosetjobs function? can you show us that function?

Comment: i just received an update from "Simo ahava". I will paste the exact wording from him "No you can't do that. A Custom JS Variable is an anonymous function with a return statement. You can't wrap it to turn it into a callback.



If you want setTimeout() functionality, you need to put it in a Custom HTML Tag.